# bash find format new line

Tags: bash, find

I running a find command which output is similar to a ls -l, I need to insert a new line but it's not working

```
find $dir_name -size $sizeFile -printf '%M %n %u %g %s %Tb %Td %Tk:%TM %p\n'
```

the output that I'm getting is like this:

```
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 26615 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/vimtutor -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 25557 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/cdlist -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/.phones -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 26615 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/vimtutor -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 26615 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/vimtutor -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/phones -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 25557 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/cdlist -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 20558 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/sample.txt -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/phones -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 25557 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/cdlist -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 20558 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/testdir1/sample.txt -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 20558 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir1/sample.txt -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 26615 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/vimtutor -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 25557 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/cdlist -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 26615 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/vimtutor -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/phones -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 25557 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/cdlist -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 26615 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/vimtutor -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/phones -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 25557 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/cdlist -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 20558 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/sample.txt -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 20558 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/testdir2/sample.txt -rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 20558 Nov 04 20:47 ./sample.dir2/sample.txt
```

does any one know what I'm missing or doing wrong???

thanks in advace for any help

Comment: The `find` command by itself gives the correct output (one entry per line) when I tested out. So the real problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
find $dir_name -size $sizeFile -printf "%M %n %u %g %s %Tb %Td %Tk:%TM %p\n"
```

(Edit: actually I just tried both double quotes and single quotes on my system, and both are correctly outputting files on separate lines)

Are you saving the output to a variable?

If you are doing something like this:

```
files=$(find $dir_name -size $sizeFile -printf '%M %n %u %g %s %Tb %Td %Tk:%TM %p\n')
echo $files
```

Then make sure you are enclosing `$files` in double quotes when you are using it:

```
echo "$files"
```

Comment: @juanp_1982 Huzzah! =) Please consider accepting / upvoting the answer if you've found it helpful

Answer (score 2):

find . -size 0 -printf  '%M %n %u %g %s %Tb\n \b%Td %Tk:%TM %p\n'

Use \n Above is an example.

By the way, if you are wanting "ls" format, there is already an option for that.
Example.

find . -size 0 -ls

Comment: the output of find ... -ls is like ls -dsli a different output from what I expect